# How to change action bar button in android

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, coding-style, back-button

I want to make the back button in the action bar to look like this "<" and not arrow like "<-". Please let me know how to do it.

Comment: Have you tried to use search? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13259055/customize-android-action-bar?rq=1

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9265774/5245903

Comment: what you have tried so far? post your java or xml code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In you activity `onCreate()` method do this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ........
    ................

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.icon_arrow);

    ..........
    ...................
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

**For Icon:**

If you are using `Android Studio`, then you can easily add icons.

1. Right click on drawable folder > New > Image Asset
2. Choose icon type "Actionbar and Tab icons"
3. Click on `Clip art` to choose your desired icon
4. Change theme as per your needs > Next
5. Finish

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ferdous.

Comment: Where can I download the arrow icon

Comment: If you are using androidstudio, then you can easily add icons. Just right click on drawable folder > New > Image Asset > chosse icon type "actionbar and tab icons" > click on clip art to choose your desired icon > change theme as per your needs > next > finish

Comment: if my answer helps to solve your problem then you should accept my answer and give an upvote. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: If you don't mind Ferdous, I had another question in the forum. Can you answer it?

Comment: I will try my best

Comment: I have already answered your another question. please check my answer. Hope it will solve your problem properly.

Answer (score 1):

Fisrt make your YourXmlFile.xml like this :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:background="#ffff"
  android:id="@+id/activity_viewsol"
  tools:context=".viewsol">
 <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linear"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_top"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_back" //Arrow Back Icon 
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
 </LinearLayout>
```

add this in YourFile.Java

```
Toolbar toolbarTop = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_top);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbarTop);
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setTitle("");
    if(actionBar != null)
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Output : 
[image]